# SQLite database created on Android and edited with Firefox SQlite manager

Tags: android, sqlite

I initially created an SQLite database on Windows and then had problems accessing it within Android.

Subsequently I created a database on Android and then copied it out. At this point it only had the android_metadata table in it.

I then imported some data via CSV and added it back into my project. The DbHelper class in my project copies the database into `/data/data/my.project/databases/`.

Now, when I run a raw query from this database, if I try to access the table imported by CSV, I get an error saying that the table doesn't exist. If I try to access the android_metadata table which I created on Android then there is no error.

The database in my assets definitely has the table in that I wish to copy over to the `/data/data/example.project/databases` folder and the copy routine is definitely called - I've checked with the log output.

Now, if I comment out the copy code, a database is automatically created which contains the android_metadata table in there and it is ~3 KB.

When the copy code is live the database is created as ~8 KB. This is the size of the database in the assets, so it appears that it has been successfully copied. However, when I pull that database back to my desktop from DDMS it is ~8 KB, but it doesn't contain the table which is in the one in the assets folder. If I manually copy directly from desktop into `/data/data`... then the database works (but this will not be possible with a market app).

Here is my copy code for copying the database:

```
public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
    Log.i(TAG, "createDatabase called");

    InputStream assetsDB = mContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
    OutputStream dbOut = new FileOutputStream(DATABASE_PATH);

    Log.i(TAG, DATABASE_PATH);
    Log.i(TAG, assetsDB.toString());

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = assetsDB.read(buffer))>0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "WritingDB block" + length);
        dbOut.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    dbOut.flush();
    dbOut.close();
    assetsDB.close();
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

I've rectified this using another example which doesn't override onCreate with the database copy code and handles the copying of the database on its own. I don't really understand why it doesn't work when calling the onCreate method.

Comment: How have you copied and in real device or emulator show some code.....

Comment: Copied to emulator at the minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen *[Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)*?

This page is a good source for the topic. But, there is a little problem. Actually, it is not a problem and explained how to fix in the page. Look at comments.

If your database is sort of largish or smallish (> 1 MB, < 100 KB (I am not sure about these values)). It seems that it is compressed and that causes confusion in the Android read on the InputStream. The trick is to rename your asset to a file that the packager will **not** try to compress. Renaming the database file from xxx to xxx.mp3 or xxx.txt or something like that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understand you, I had the same problem with loading an SQLite database from other sources (I used to the Firefox SQLite manger too).

I want to read a temporary database from the assets folder at startup and fill my application database with test data, and I usually get this error.

I need to put this code before loading my test database:

```
final SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
db.close();
```

My database helper class:

```
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context,
          DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME,
          null,
          DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;

    // Temporary copy test database
    loadMockDataBase();

    dataBase = getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public final synchronized void close() {
    if (dataBase != null) {
        dataBase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}

private void loadMockDataBase() {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    db.close();

    try {
        copyDataBase();
    }
    catch (final IOException e) {
        Log.d(SystemConfiguration.LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: If I put this snippit of code in I get an error stating that I'm recursively calling getReadableDatabase. I'm not sure that we have the same problem.